# psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, psql

I have an app with `Postgres` with a `VirtualBox` machine which I control with `Vagrant`.
I think it was because of an unfortunate packages updates today I'm not able to connect with the Database anymore. 
When I run:

```
psql -U password -d database -h localhost -p 9001
```

I get the following error:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly 
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

I have reinstall/upgrade `Vagrant`, `VirtualBox` and `Postgres` with no results.

I've been looking for answers here and I check the `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.config` as other users sugested.

In my case, the file `postgresql.conf` already has the line

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

The file `pg_hba.config` has this record too:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

My Vagrantfile contains:

```
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6543, host: 9000
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 9001
```

I've spent hours trying to solve this issue.

Comment: What version postgre do you use?

Comment: I'm using Postgres 9.6 and it's mandatory